# Android studio recyclerview retrofit

Tags: android, recyclerview, retrofit

Не работает ресайклвью. Почему - не знаю. Объясните

Код адаптера:

```
public class WeatherForecastAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WeatherForecastAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    WeatherForecast weatherForecast;

    public WeatherForecastAdapter(Context context, WeatherForecast weatherForecast) {
        this.context = context;
        this.weatherForecast = weatherForecast;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.forecastweather_item, viewGroup, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {

        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(new StringBuilder("http://openweathermap.org/img/w/")
                        .append(weatherForecast.getList().get(i).getWeather().get(0).getIcon())
                        .append(".png").toString())
                .into(myViewHolder.imageForecast);

//        myViewHolder.dateForecast.setText(Common.convertUnixToDate(weatherForecast.getList().get(i).getDt()));

        myViewHolder.tempForecast.setText(new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(weatherForecast.getList().get(i).getMain().getTemp())).append("°C"));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return weatherForecast.getList().size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView dateForecast;
        TextView tempForecast;
        ImageView imageForecast;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            dateForecast = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDateforecast);
            tempForecast = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTempforecast);
            imageForecast = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivImageforecast);
        }
    }
}
```

В onCreate создал

```
recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv_forecast);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

адаптер выставил в методе, который выполняет запрос

```
Call<WeatherForecast> callForecast = api.getForecast(lat, lng, units, key);
        callForecast.enqueue(new Callback<WeatherForecast>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<WeatherForecast> call, Response<WeatherForecast> response) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onResponse");
                WeatherForecast data = response.body();

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    WeatherForecastAdapter adapter = new WeatherForecastAdapter(MainActivity.this, data);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<WeatherForecast> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onFailure");
                Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
            }
        });
```

пс. приложение о погоде, и есть запрос на погоду текущего дня - все работает. А вот сам ресайкл вообще не отображается

вот ещё лайаут к ресайклу (R.layout.forecastweather_item):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDateforecast"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="date  "
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTempforecast"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="temp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivImageforecast"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:drawingCacheQuality="high" />

</LinearLayout>
```

в активити мейн создал

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_forecast"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Comment: Не понятно, что у вас за ошибка

Comment: @pavel163 не отображается сам ресайклвью в рабочем состоянии приложения. приложение запускается, элементы сверху работают а ниже (там ресайклвью) пусто.

Comment: А что дебаг говорит? `if (response.isSuccessful())` срабатывает? А то у вас тишина в случае неуспешного запроса, `else` отсутствует.

Comment: @Eugene Krivenja спасибо, теперь понял что проблема в том, что получаю call onFailure. буду что то с этим делать , хотя пока не вижу в чем проблема

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была в методе call, а точнее срабатывало onFailure.

Проблема была в модели приложения (приходило в переменную int число с плавающей точкой).